# Is it possible to manipulate the return value in the chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Google's Chrome browser has a nice feature which shows you the return value in the debugger before you step out of the function. It shows up in the `Scope` list in one of the debugger panes along with `Watch`, `Call Stack`, etc. [It looks like this](https://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1557300008000&name=Screenshot-return-value.png&token=ABZ6GAeZ8uT1MiGMu2uVnlHlOT1L-IRa2Q%3A1444754997929&id=155730&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAdoxp39f_N3EhKH0y20xrpF-dLNgA%3A1444754997929&inline=1).

I'm curious if there's console access to this variable?

I frequently have a need to do something like this while debugging:

```
<return>.filter(function(z) { return z >= 0; })
```

Or any other arbitrary way to understand whether the return value was what I was expecting. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to refer to `<return>` in the console. I was hoping there was some variable like `$_` that would give me access, but I haven't found look looking in the [likely places](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks).

I realize I can look at the `<return>` object as it appears in the `Scope` list but if the item is a large array or complex object, etc., I would prefer to type some code into the debugger while paused at a breakpoint to see if I'm getting what I expect.

What I typically resort to is modifying my code to save the return value to a variable, and then reproducing the steps to get back to the breakpoint, but this is annoying.

Thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to hack?

Comment: Run your code in the console when it's paused. Also, you can set a watch expression.

Comment: when you `console.log()` the output in some way, you can right click the output in the console and store it as a global variable, from there you can access the data and manipulate as necessary of course this is a temporary value, so it will disappear when you leave the current page session

Comment: The `Store as Global Variable` menu item isn't available when clicking on the return value, `<return>` in the `Scope` list. So, unfortunately it doesn't work like a variable that was output from `console.log()`.

Comment: @Malk, my problem is that I want to write a line of code that references the return value that was not saved into a variable before returning. For example, if I have `return new SomeClass();` and I want to see what the instance that will be returned looks like while paused in the debugger, there's no way for me to do this without either poking through the `<return>` object in the `Scope` menu or by modifying my code to save the object before returning and then re-running the code to get back there and look at it.

Comment: Chrome is now (March 2017) offering the `Store as Global Variable` context menu option on `<Return Value>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Store as Global Variable` works in google chrome now, using `Version 56.0.2924.87`.

So, you step to the close brace of your function in the Sources tab, then context-click the *Return Value*, and choose `Store as Global Variable`.

The console tab will show something like

```
temp1 = ▶ MyClass {...}
```

From there on you can access temp1 just like any other variable in the console.